# How to add '$' after '-' in SQL Query when formatting for currency

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The following SQL will render the value as show here:`$-541.42`

```
'$'+CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(MONEY, MYCOLUMN), 1)
```

How do I have the format as shown here: `-$541.42`

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in SQL Server? this is something that you'd do in a reporting layer with the correct format (SSRS, Excel etc).

Comment: You can do it with string manipulation, but I think that gets too complicated too fast. The easiest method is a simple `case`, which checks if value is `< 0` or `>= 0`. Do the formatting in the relevant `THEN`'s.

Comment: Rich Benner is right. Once you've converted the numeric value to string, you can't manipulate it or total it. And you can't easily change the formatting - what happens if some users want thousands separators, for instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN @val < 0 THEN '-' ELSE '' END)+
    '$'+CONVERT(VARCHAR, ABS(CONVERT(MONEY, @val)), 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a cute alternative that doesn't use `case`:

```
replace('$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), CONVERT(MONEY, MYCOLUMN), 1), '$-', '-$')
```

Note:  You should always include a length when using `varchar` in SQL Server.  The default length varies by context and might not be sufficient