# Changing formatting of currency

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Money](
    [MoneyValue] [money] NOT NULL
)
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Money] ([MoneyValue]) VALUES (99.9900)
INSERT [dbo].[Money] ([MoneyValue]) VALUES (-99.9900)
GO
```

The following query:

```
select 
CONCAT('$', MoneyValue) 
from 
Money
```

returns the following results

```
$99.99
$-99.99
```

Is there a way I can return the results as the following instead?

```
$99.99
-$99.99
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36914842/how-to-add-after-in-sql-query-when-formatting-for-currency/36915007#36915007

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should really leave all formatting to your presentation layer, but if for whatever reason you *must* do this in SQL you can use [`FORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
SELECT FORMAT([MoneyValue], '$0.00')
FROM dbo.[Money]
```

but beware of doing this on large sets, [it may not perform well](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but).

Comment: Thanks Gareth, accepting your answer as it seems from the useful votes, it's the best solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `replace()` :

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONCAT('$', MoneyValue), '$-', '-$')
FROM Money;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @money MONEY = -123

SELECT 
    REPLACE(CONCAT('$', @money) ,'$-','-$')
```

Answer (score 0):

As another alternative to the already posted answers, you can use `replicate()` and `sign()` to put a `'-'` in front of it, when the number is negative. Then `concat()` the `'$'` and the *absolute* value (using `abs()`).

```
SELECT concat(replicate('-', -sign(moneyvalue)), '$', abs(moneyvalue))
       FROM money;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=1216d8006c96f2fa5e42353eb2f38d26)

Be aware, that `replicate()` returns `NULL` for zero or negative lengths. In a `concat()` that is no problem, as `concat()` converts nulls to empty strings. But if you use the `+` string concatenation operator instead, you'd have to do that conversion yourself (using `coalesce()` or `isnull()` etc.).